# Convert string to date(0512 should be converted to May 2012)

Tags: iphone, ios, datepicker

How to convert a string to date? I know we can use dateFormatter to do this but I am stuck in between. I have format 0512 which should be converted to May 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
    NSString *finalDate = @"0512";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMyy"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:finalDate];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM yyyy"];

    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: :thanx a lot, u saved me.

Comment: Be wary I've used this and: 12/49 will give you Dec 2049 and then 01/50 will return Jan 1950

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMyy"];
    NSDate *dateObj= [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"0512"];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateObj);
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateObj]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code may be helped you..

```
  NSString *dateStr = @"0512";

    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

    // Convert date object to desired output format
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM YYYY"];
    dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    [dateFormat release];


    NSLog(@"%@",dateStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is so difficult about it?
1. Take out first 2 characters of string
2. Put if else/ convert string to int and use switch to make up month
3. Take the next 2 characters, add them to 2000 and you get year

Now user iOS functions to achieve this :)